# Expo eject results in error Cannot read property 'resources' of null

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I created an app using expo. Now, I want to eject the application and I did

`expo eject`

After this, I get the following error:

```
Warning! Your git working tree is dirty.
It's recommended to commit all your changes before proceeding, so you can revert the changes made by this command if necessary.

✔ Would you like to proceed? … yes

✔ Created native projects | /android, /ios already created | gitignore already synced
✔ Updated package.json and added index.js entry point for iOS and Android.
 Using Yarn to install packages. Pass --npm to use npm instead.
✔ Installed JavaScript dependencies.
Cannot read property 'resources' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resources' of null
    at setColorItem (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/Documents/work/convergetree/doodle/weather-app-react-native/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/android/Colors.ts:19:29)
    at Object.assignColorValue (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/Documents/work/convergetree/doodle/weather-app-react-native/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/android/Colors.ts:63:12)
    at setSplashColorsForTheme (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/Documents/work/convergetree/doodle/weather-app-react-native/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/src/plugins/unversioned/expo-splash-screen/withAndroidSplashStyles.ts:79:17)
    at /Users/kshitijbajracharya/Documents/work/convergetree/doodle/weather-app-react-native/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/src/plugins/unversioned/expo-splash-screen/withAndroidSplashStyles.ts:23:25
    at action (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/Documents/work/convergetree/doodle/weather-app-react-native/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/withMod.ts:214:29)
    at interceptingMod (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/Documents/work/convergetree/doodle/weather-app-react-native/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/withMod.ts:100:27)
    at evalModsAsync (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/mod-compiler.ts:145:32)
    at compileModsAsync (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/src/plugins/mod-compiler.ts:82:10)
    at configureManagedProjectAsync (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/eject/configureProjectAsync.ts:63:12)
    at prebuildAsync (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/eject/prebuildAsync.ts:92:25)
    at ejectAsync (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/eject/ejectAsync.ts:23:19)
    at actionAsync (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/eject.ts:47:5)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/kshitijbajracharya/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:350:7)
```

How do I resolve this? Where is the `resource` that is being set to null?

Comment: How did you solve this? Running into the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to latest expo-cli version:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

> Run commands were introduced in SDK 41.

You can use  `expo prebuild`

> expo prebuild
>
> Experimental: Create native iOS and Android project
> files before building natively. Learn more:
> https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

[Documents for reference](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/prebuilding.md)

[image]

Comment: Does this mean prebuild should be preferred over eject?

Comment: Still getting the same error `Cannot read property 'resources' of null` after prebuild

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it was solved by removing `colors.xml`.

```
android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml
```